# SQL statement is not giving the last three days

Tags: mysql

I have the following SQL:

```
SELECT 
    DATE(`date`), SUM(`total`)
FROM
    `order`
WHERE
    `status` = '3'
        AND `date` > DATE(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY)
GROUP BY DAY(`date`)
ORDER BY `date` DESC;
```

Today is 2014-03-27.  But when I var_dump results from this query, I get the following (edited  down to save space, numbers edited out)

```
array(28) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["DATE(`date`)"]=>
    string(10) "2014-03-24"
    ["SUM(`total`)"]=>
    string(17) "xxx"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["DATE(`date`)"]=>
    string(10) "2014-03-23"
    ["SUM(`total`)"]=>
    string(6) "xxx"
```

..And it finished on 2014-02-25.  There are definitely records from the last three days, i can see them in the table.  When I run `SELECT CURDATE();` I get 2014-03-27.  Why is not showing me the last three days?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing

```
GROUP BY DAY(`date`)
```

while it should be

```
GROUP BY DATE(`date`)
```

`DAY()` returns the day of the month for date, from 1 to 31, so there could be same value for different months.

Comment: That fixed it.  But can you explain to me why this happened?

Comment: @Chud37 Added the explaination.

Comment: Why was it not selecting curdate records when the table has such record?

Comment: Only 28 days in Feb, hence the 27th of Feb and the 27th of March are within the last 30 days and both have the same value for DAY(`date`). MySQL picks one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the below Code ..It will display last three days record

```
SELECT 
    DATE(`date`), SUM(`total`)
FROM
    `order`
WHERE
    `status` = '3'
        AND **DATEDIFF**(DAY, date,GETDATE()) <= 3

ORDER BY `date` DESC;
```

`DATEDIFF` Function will return the difference between two days based on the datepart. Here we use the DAY as datepart